# Selecting cities that have a combination of products in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following dataset, that have the prices for many products and cities:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
    the_id varchar(5) NOT NULL, 
    the_date timestamp NOT NULL,
    the_city varchar(5) NOT NULL,
    the_product varchar(1) NOT NULL,
    the_price numeric(4,2) NOT NULL 
);

INSERT INTO my_table
VALUES ('VIS01', '2019-05-02 09:00:00','LISBO','A',8), 
       ('VIS02', '2019-05-04 12:00:00','EVORA','A',7), 
       ('VIS03', '2019-05-05 18:00:00','LISBO','B',5), 
       ('VIS04', '2019-05-06 18:30:00','PORTO','B',5), 
       ('VIS05', '2019-05-15 12:05:00','PORTO','A',6), 
       ('VIS06', '2019-05-18 18:06:00','EVORA','B',4),
       ('VIS07', '2019-05-23 18:07:00','PORTO','C',10),
       ('VIS08', '2019-05-26 18:08:00','EVORA','E',14),
       ('VIS09', '2019-06-07 18:09:00','LISBO','B',5),
       ('VIS10', '2019-06-09 18:10:00','LISBO','D',11),
       ('VIS11', '2019-06-12 18:11:00','EVORA','C',10),
       ('VIS12', '2019-06-15 18:12:00','LISBO','D',11),
       ('VIS13', '2019-06-15 18:13:00','EVORA','A',7),
       ('VIS14', '2019-06-18 18:14:00','PORTO','A',6),
       ('VIS15', '2019-06-23 18:15:00','LISBO','A',8),
       ('VIS16', '2019-06-25 18:16:00','LISBO','A',8),
       ('VIS17', '2019-06-27 18:17:00','PORTO','B',5),
       ('VIS18', '2019-06-27 18:18:00','LISBO','D',11),
       ('VIS19', '2019-06-28 18:19:00','LISBO','A',8),
       ('VIS20', '2019-06-30 18:20:00','EVORA','B',4),
       ('VIS21', '2019-07-01 18:21:00','EVORA','A',6),
       ('VIS22', '2019-07-04 18:30:00','EVORA','D',10),
       ('VIS23', '2019-07-04 18:31:00','EVORA','B',3),
       ('VIS24', '2019-07-06 18:40:00','EVORA','C',11),
       ('VIS25', '2019-07-12 18:50:00','EVORA','E',14),
       ('VIS26', '2019-07-15 18:00:00','PORTO','A',7),
       ('VIS27', '2019-07-18 18:00:00','PORTO','C',11),
       ('VIS28', '2019-07-25 18:00:00','PORTO','B',4),
       ('VIS29', '2019-07-30 18:00:00','PORTO','A',9),
       ('VIS30', '2019-07-30 18:00:00','LISBO','A',7);
```

What I want is to have the average price for each month and each city but it has to follow a rule, that it should have the combination of certain products. Let's say that the product should be A and B strictly, then the expected table is:

```
month     city     product    avg_price
2019-05   EVORA    A          7
2019-05   EVORA    B          4
2019-05   LISBO    A          8
2019-05   LISBO    B          5
2019-05   PORTO    A          6
2019-05   PORTO    B          5
2019-06   EVORA    A          7
2019-06   EVORA    B          4
2019-06   LISBO    A          8
2019-06   LISBO    B          5
2019-06   PORTO    A          6
2019-06   PORTO    B          5
2019-07   EVORA    A          6
2019-07   EVORA    B          3
2019-07   PORTO    A          8
2019-07   PORTO    B          4
```

As you see, in this case `LISBO` doesn't appear in `2019-07` because the condition "A and B" strictly doesn't hold.

I have tried this code:

```
select date_trunc('month', the_date) as month, the_city, the_product, AVG(the_price) avg_price
FROM my_table
where the_product in ('A','B')
group by month, the_city, the_product
order by month desc
```

But I don't know how to apply the condition. Please, could you help me with this question? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you need in rows then you need to group by product as well:

```
select
    the_city,
    date_trunc('month', the_date) as yearmonth,
    the_product ,
    avg(the_price) as a_avg
from
(
    select * 
    , sum(case when the_product = 'A' then 1 end) over (partition by date_trunc('month', the_date), the_city) acount
    , sum(case when the_product = 'B' then 1 end) over (partition by date_trunc('month', the_date), the_city) bcount
    from my_table
    where  the_product in ('A','B')
) t 
where t.acount > 0 and t.bcount > 0 
group by the_city, yearmonth,the_product
order by yearmonth, the_city;
```

Comment: Hello @eshirvana, I tested your answer but LISBO appears on month 2019-07, and it shouldn't appear because it should have the combination A and B strictly.

Comment: @Alexis I see your point now , that would complicate your query , see my updated answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer and time @eshirvana, interesting how you applied a restriction by flagging the combination

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest putting the prices in *columns* not *rows*:

```
select the_city, date_trunc('month', the_date) as yyyymm,
       avg(the_price) filter (where the_product = 'A') as a_avg,
       avg(the_price) filter (where the_product = 'B') as b_avg
from my_table
group by the_city, yyyymm
having count(*) filter (where the_product = 'A') > 0 and
       count(*) filter (where the_product = 'B') > 0
order by yyyymm, the_city;
```

If you really want rows, then one option is to unpivot afterwards.  But columns make more sense to me for what you are asking for.

Comment: Hello @Gordon Linoff, the answer is great, but just a question, is it possible to have the data as rows? It happens that the product basket could have more than 38 items, so the condition for count and avg should have each product. Thank you